# Use INNER JOIN for update sql data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress, syntax

i want change post_status in wordpress database from draft to trash for duplicate post that have same post_title and i use this sql query

```
      UPDATE a.post_status SET `post_status` = 'trash'
        FROM wp_posts AS a
         INNER JOIN (
           SELECT post_title, MIN( id ) AS min_id
           FROM wp_posts
           WHERE post_type = 'post'
           AND post_status = 'draft'
           GROUP BY post_title
           HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1
         ) AS b ON b.post_title = a.post_title
        AND b.min_id <> a.id
        AND a.post_type = 'post'
        AND a.post_status = 'draft'
```

error display after execute the query

```
  Error Code: 1064
    Erreur de syntaxe près de 'FROM wp_posts AS a
     INNER JOIN (
       SELECT post_title, MIN( id ) AS min_id
      ' à la ligne 2
```

what's the correct syntax for this query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax in MySQL does not use `FROM`:

```
UPDATE post_status ps INNER JOIN
       (SELECT post_title, MIN( id ) AS min_id
        FROM wp_posts
        WHERE post_type = 'post' AND
              post_status = 'draft'
        GROUP BY post_title
        HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1
       ) p
       ON p.post_title = ps.post_title AND
          p.min_id <> ps.id AND
          ps.post_type = 'post' AND
          ps.post_status = 'draft'
 SET ps.post_status = 'trash';
```

Note that I also changed the table aliases from meaningless letters to more meaningful abbreviations.

Comment: thank you Gordon for the answer in this syntax i find other error is 

`Error Code: 1146 Table 'a.post_status' does not exist`

Comment: @hassanii Try it now.